# How do we denote $\mathbb{F}[x]$ where the polynomial must have a certain degree?

Tags: polynomials, notation

We usually define $\mathbb{F}[x]$ to be the set of polynomials with coefficients from a field $\mathbb{F}$. If we want this polynomial to have degree $n$, what is the standard notation? $\mathbb{F}_n[x]$ can't be used, because this is the set of polynomials with coefficients from a field with $n$ elements. I am not looking to write these separately as "$\mathbb{F}[x]$ with $\deg{f} = n.$" What is the standard notation? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, that seems like standard notation to me. Any reason you dont want to use it?

Comment: Really it's just because the problem I'm working on requires defining functions from this polynomial space to another vector space. For example, writing $T: \mathbb{F}[x] \to \mathbb{F}$ with $\deg f = n$ is just extremely clunky, especially when repeated. @QC_QAOA

Comment: You could always just say: Define $T(\mathbb{F},n)$ as the polynomials in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ with degree $n$. Then it isn't as clunky

Comment: That's fair. Thank you.